# mysql and php : good way to store my data and to select in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mysql table of properties that looks like that:

```
Properties : [

{

    property_id: 1,

    name: "property1"

},

{

    property_id: 2,

    name: "property2"

}

]
```

Then i have a table of elements that looks like that:

```
Elements : [

{

    element_id: 1,

    name: "element1"

},

{

    element_id: 2,

    name: "element2"

}

]
```

I would like that each element has its own list of properties it can have.
So i tough i will give an array with the properties id to each element:

```
Elements : [

{

    element_id: 1,

    name: "element1"

    properties_id: [1, 2] // This array of id is serialized with php and stored as text

}
```

]

But i know it is not the good way of doing it so i need your help.
All i want is to be able to query my database and have the following result:

```
Elements_and_their_Properties : [

{

    element_id: 1,

    element_name: "element1",

    element_properties: [

        { property_id: 1, property_name: "property1" },

        { property_id: 2, property_name: "property2" }

    ]

},

{

    element_id: 2,

    element_name: "element2",

    element_properties: [

        { property_id: 1, property_name: "property1" }

    ]

}

]
```

Is there a nice and clean way to do that in one query ?
Thanks !

Comment: You're using a very well known SQL antipattern. See [SQL Antipatterns chapter 2 - Jaywalking](http://kysmykseka.net/kysmyk/Wizardry/Programming/Pragmatic%20Programmers/SQL%20Antipatterns.pdf). Start by fixing your schema.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I swear i will read the 334 pages pdf but can you please give me the good practice to have in my case.

Comment: I already know that if i link every property to its parent i could do an easy LEFT JOIN on element_id = property_parent_id.
But this would make me duplicate properties if their parent is different. Would that be the best way ?

Comment: The only thing you're going to duplicate is (indexed) ids. The "elements and their properties" should be separate table where one row represents one relation between element and property. 3 rows in your example (element_id,property_id) = (1,1),(1,2),(2,1)